# View All Devices on the Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am looking for a way to view clients on the network in a central location that is easily accessible and always up to date. I know that I can use arp tables or network scanning, however this is not a long term solution that lists clients. I have used the UniFi controller which provides a list of clients connected, however my network has a mixture of devices(not all of them UniFi) preventing me from seeing everything.

While it is definitely true that if I wanted to detect a malicious user, I would have to scan the network. I am looking for a simple network overview solution similar to [this](https://support.eero.com/hc/en-us/articles/207895143-Where-do-I-view-the-devices-on-my-network-) or the UniFi controller that I mentioned earlier.

Is there a universal (simple and easily accessible, mobile) solution that will provide information of clients currently connected?

Comment: Ping all IP through that subnet using `for` loop in terminal. And you can get an updated ARP table.

Comment: I understand that I can obtain network devices from an arp table, but I am looking for some way to have this information always available. I want a live monitoring solution.

Comment: I was looking for a general solution that I can place on the network or in line to monitor clients and provide statistics like data usage.

Comment: switched networks preclude that kind of approach unless at some point, all traffic goes out a single port which can be monitored. most networks don't have a point at which such monitoring could occur, unless you set up an IDPS with port mirroring between all your switches/APs which is beyond most hobbiest's scope.

Comment: I've added some more information about the specifics about what I was looking for. I hope to at least have an overview of what is on the network even if it doesn't catch malicious users. @FrankThomas

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, and will probably never be a single way to track every device on the network, without performing active scanning (at least if you are worried about malicious parties). My recommendation for scanners is nmap/Zenmap.

Passive scanning won't detect devices that don't send traffic on a path that the passive scanner is listening on. If you have an IDPS solution, and have configured mirroring end-to-end, or taps connected to each switch on a mirrored port, then that would work, but that requires enterprise grade switches and other infrastructure.

ARP only works for devices that are sending traffic to or through the device you are inspecting. on a switched network, traffic isn't sent to unintended parties, so unless the unknown device attempted to connect to the device you are checking, it would not turn up.

As you say, Wifi APs only provide info on Wifi clients, and DHCP servers would miss statically assigned IPs. Switch address tables are isolated, so you'd have to ask each switch, and will do no good about a system that sends no traffic, or attacks the switch, likely with an ARP flood.

Of course, this is assuming that you are interested in detecting unauthorized devices. If you are comfortable with just seeing the devices that aren't trying to sneak in, then just make it a rule that all devices get their addresses via DHCP (use reservations for network/server devices). then you can just check the client list from the DHCP server. You would have to adjust your lease time to whatever interval you consider "being online" is for your purposes.

Comment: This is definitely true. I currently run Sophos XG which displays connections by ips on the network, however, it misses the ability to perform a reverse dns lookup on the ip for a hostname. I was looking for a similar solution to this. I understand, however, not all devices will be detected if they do not access the internet through the firewall. I am looking for something like [this](https://support.eero.com/hc/en-us/articles/207895143-Where-do-I-view-the-devices-on-my-network-), for example, that will work in a general network.

Comment: well, product recommendations are frowned upon here, and I don't know of any that tick all your boxes. Sorry.